# NGINX proxy pass to separate port for route starting with /api

Tags: nginx

I will preface this with, this is technically working.

I am trying to use a single page react application (SPA) that proxies an api with the same cname.domainname.com.

The api is just a basic node REST api with a root path at `/api` instead of `/`.
I set up my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file with the following server. (my website domain switched out with generics)

(I copy an pasted the server from a guide and changed it to meet my needs)

Two Questions:

1. Do I need to declare root on a SPA? (My root is wrong currently and everything is working, so it doesn't seem important for SPAs)
2. Is this the "correct" way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

```
server {
   root /opt/htdocs/usefulread;
   index index.html index.htm;
   server_name cname.domainname.com;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5030/; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5031; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   # SSL stuff removed for simplicity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not serve any static files with nginx, then the content of `root` directive does not matter.

However, it is beneficial to serve static assets with nginx, because it is really efficient in serving files to clients.

Backends should concentrate on serving dynamic content.

Comment: Is it possible to use it to serve the js and css of my react app? Could I just put the path up to where the react path starts (obviously starting from the top level directory not the application folder)

Comment: Yes, that is the usual use case with nginx.